# Count the number of if statements in a file

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to read in a file of code and count the number of if-statements. How would I be able to go about doing this using AST.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are there any tools you're having specific errors with, or a particular thing you're not understanding?

Comment: You didn't say which source you are reading. I assume you are reading Python sources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python has a standard lib `ast`:

```
# assume you are reading Python source
import ast

with open('src.py') as f:
    src = f.read()

tree = ast.parse(src)
cnt_if = sum([x for x in ast.walk(tree) if isinstance(x, ast.If)])
```